# How to select css text using regex?

Tags: javascript

Can someone suggest a regex for selecting/ separating out a keyvalue pair in css rules and casting them in to an object;

```
//css rules
animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-name: none; animation-play-state: running;
```

into this:

```
{
'animation-iteration-count': 1, 'animation-name': none, 'animation-play-state': running 
}
```

and/or this:

```
[
{key: 'animation-iteration-count', value: 1},
{key: 'animation-name', value:none },
{key: 'animation-play-state', value: running },
]
```

**REGEX Preferred** if possible (or vanilla js if not)

Comment: Do you want to read all the css content and create an array for the animation properties?

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: Yes. This css will be in text format. So I want to cast it in to an object. An object is preferred as final result as objects are faster than arrays. So that I can easily read styles and apply.

Comment: It is necessary. I have a used case where I receive a list of css rules as text & I want to apply them using javascript. This is a bit of dynamic styling... Please suggest a regex

Comment: I believe splitting the array with `.split()` may be better than using a regex.

Comment: Do you intend to do validation as well, or only valid css should come?

Comment: What do you mean by validation? I need to split the css in to separate rules using regex (we can select using semicolor) and then cast in to an object as demonstrated above. If validation is possible you can suggest that also.
Thanks.

Comment: @mex there is a lot more to css than you seem to give it credit :) I tried pointed that out in my answer, with a suggested alternative approach as well

Comment: Great. Thanks. I really liked regex...

Comment: @mex I like a lamborgini as well, doesn't mean I would go and drive off-road with it :)

Comment: @mex If you have one problem and you try to solve it using regex, you now have two problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the css you have shown, you could do it without using regex, in the following way:

```js
const cssText = 'font-family: "Verdana"; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-name: none; animation-play-state: running;';

function parseCssText( css ) {
  return css.split(';').reduce( (dict, rule) => {
    const [key,value] = rule.split(':');
    if (!value) {
      // skip key only
      return dict;
    }
    dict[key.trim()] = value.trim();
    return dict;
  }, {});
}

console.log( parseCssText( cssText ) );
```

It of course has a couple of limitations:

- Double keys will be overwritten
- When a semi colon is present other than as a separator between the rule/value it would break
- colon inside a value would break the parsing as well

From your original question, one could argue that having the values as you display them, would be wrong, unless you declare variables as `none` or `running`, all values should always be represented as strings. That's why you also see the quotation marks around `"Verdana"` in the output, which indicates that this is a string value

There would be a lot of things you would have to take care of, and I could only wonder why you wouldn't take an easier approach and apply the styling onto an element instead. The browser could then take care of the parsing and you would achieve a better result, or at least, a less error prone one :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but I wrote the following in PHP to give you a good start:

```
<?php
function cssJSON($fileName){
  $css = preg_replace('/(?<![a-z])\s+|\n+|\r+/i', '', file_get_contents($fileName));
  preg_match_all('/[^\/}]+{[^}]+}/', $css, $a); $m = $a[0]; $r = [];
  foreach($m as $c){
    $o = new StdClass; $q = explode('{', $c); $o->selectors = explode(',', $q[0]); $x = preg_replace('/;*}$/', '', $q[1]); $s = explode(';', $x); $o->style = [];
    foreach($s as $c){
      $z = explode(':', $c); $w = explode('-', $z[0]); $g = $z[1]; $b = new StdClass;
      if(isset($w[1])){
        $b->{$w[0].ucfirst($w[1])} = $g;
      }
      else{
        $b->{$w[0]} = $g;
      }
      $o->style[] = $b;
    }
    $r[] = $o;
  }
  return json_encode($r);
}
// usage
$json = cssJSON('css/external.css');
?>
```

It returns an Array of Objects that have a `selectors` Array of Strings and a `style` Array of Objects. Loop away!